# How to query this with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am working on a project. For now let's say I have 3 tables `"districts", "crimes" and "cases"`. The cases table holds all the registered cases.

Case.php (EDIT : missing quote)

```
class Case extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cases';
    protected $fillable = ['person_name','crime_id' ,'district_id','crime_date'];

    public function crime()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Crime');
    }

}
```

District.php

```
class District extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'districts';
    protected $fillable = ['name']; // name of districts like "A district","B district" etc.

    public function cases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Case');
    }
}
```

Crime.php

```
class Crime extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'crimes';
    protected $fillable = ['name']; // name of different types of crime like rape, murder etc.
}
```

My output at the end of month should look like below in report.blade.php
for eg: Total crime in A district in Decemeber, Total crime of B district in December, Total crime of C district in December. Simillary for all districts in every month (jan-dec of every year)

```
  District name | total crime | crime
   A               3             rape
                                 murder
                                 attempt to murder

   B               1             rape

   C               0             No crime reported
```

// ie: above is the data for december month of 2017 in every district

Controller: I need to modify this query to get above output because this give total crime and types of crime in each district but regardless of every month

```
public function index(){
    $districts =  District::with('cases.crime')->get();
    return $districts;
}
```

on return I got this

```
[
{
id: 1,
name: "A",//name of district
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
cases: [   //registered cases
    {
    id: 1,
    crime_id: 1,
    district_id: 1,
    crime_date: "2017-12-31 00:00:00",
    created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
crime: {//name of crime from crimes table
id: 1,
name: "Rape",
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}
},
{
id: 3,
crime_id: 4,
district_id: 1,
crime_date: "2017-12-31 00:00:00",
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
crime: {
id: 4,
name: "Women trafficking",
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}
},
{
id: 4,
crime_id: 3,
district_id: 1,
crime_date: "2017-12-31 00:00:00",
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
crime: {
id: 3,
name: "Murder",
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}
}
]
},
{
id: 2,
name: "B",//name of district from districts table
created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    cases: [   
    {
    id: 2,
    crime_id: 1,
    district_id: 2,
    crime_date: "2017-12-31 00:00:00",
    created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    updated_at:  "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    crime: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Rape",
    created_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    updated_at: "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}
}
]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
$districts = District::with(['cases' => function ($query) use($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->whereBetween('crime_date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
}, 'cases.crime'])->get();
```

construct `$startDate` and `$endDate` from your Month and year.

for more info have a look at this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
(Constraining Eager Loads section)